# Encoding iOS captured video to MPEG4

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, mpeg-4, avasset

I'm developing a social video app which a user can capture a video or choose one from his photo library.
The videos are not playing on android devices, and after some research we figured out that we should encode the videos on both sided to `MPEG4` format.

Iv'e tried using `AVAsset` and `AVMutableComposition`, and the thing is that it generates VERY BIG files.
a 20 seconds video was generated to 15 MB!

I guess I'm not the first to run into this issue, so please if you have any clue, let me know.
Thanks!

***EDIT***

OK, the file size problem was in this line

```
AVAssetExportSession *finalExporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPreset960x540];
```

changed it to:

```
AVAssetExportSession *finalExporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
```

now the problem is it rotated left, sometimes right... and sometimes upside down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't try it, but

you can check these link:

[MOV to Mp4 video conversion iPhone Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474517/mov-to-mp4-video-conversion-iphone-programmatically)

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html

or may use ffmpeg from http://ffmpeg.org/

http://ilpleut.be/code-ffmpeg

https://github.com/xiewei-wayne

Comment: thanks, the first link was helpful, do you know the order of the AVAssetExportPreset by quality?

Comment: please check the link regarding order : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44898852/difference-between-various-avassetexportpreset