# Difference between various AVAssetExportPreset

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I am compressing video so i have come across following Export Presets

```
AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality

AVAssetExportPreset640x480
AVAssetExportPreset960x540
AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
```

I have read about all of them in apple documents and found that second list compressed in given fixed dimensions but found nothing about first list , i am confused that why it has 2 lists one with low, medium and high quality and other with fixed sizes and which one is better to use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The AVAssetExportPreset containing below available preset names.

[**1. Export Preset Names for Device-Appropriate QuickTime Files**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportsession/export_preset_names_for_device_appropriate_quicktime_files)

```
AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality - Specifies a low quality QuickTime file.
AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality - Specifies a medium quality QuickTime file.
AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality - Specifies a high quality QuickTime file.
```

> You use these export options to produce QuickTime .mov files with
>   video size appropriate to the current device.

[**2. Export Preset Names for QuickTime Files of a Given Size**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportsession/export_preset_names_for_quicktime_files_of_a_given_size)

```
AVAssetExportPreset640x480
AVAssetExportPreset960x540
AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160
```

You use these export options to produce QuickTime .mov files with a specified video size.

[**3. Export Preset Name for iTunes Audio**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportsession/export_preset_name_for_itunes_audio)

```
AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A
```

You use this export option to produce an audio-only .m4a file with appropriate iTunes gapless playback data.

[**4. Export Preset Name for Pass-Through**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportsession/export_preset_name_for_pass_through)

```
AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough
```

You use this export option to let all tracks pass through.This option does not show up in the 
allExportPresets()
 and 
exportPresets(compatibleWith:)
 methods.

Comment: Which one is most recommended to use, to compress videos which allows uploading and downloading faster with a good quality,?

Comment: @khushboo i think MediumQuality is best one for faster process & quality too.