# Video conversion in iOS

Tags: ios, video, video-conversion

I write app on iOS and I need to use video conversion features. The features whatI need is:

- reduce resolution of video
- cut video (to squere for instance)
- reduce bit rate of video
- rotate video
- save video in mp4 format

My problem is that I have only a little experience in iOS and I dont know how I can do this. I know that I cant use FFMpeg becouse of its license. I heard there is a build-in AV Foundation framework. Can I perform such things using this framework. If no is there any other way to do this.

Comment: check this tutorial you can achieve all this using AVFoundation framework http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios 2.http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Comment: @prasad I assume that there will no problems with dynamically loading video or use iPhone camera to record movie and then make some conversions without play video to user and then save it or send to server, right?

Comment: yes, you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

MPMoviePlayerController will help:

1.yes - u can do this, but u should consider to do this offline

2.yes - adjust the `MPMoviePlayerController` view size

3.yes - u can do this, but u should consider to do this offline

4.yes

5.Don't understand - u have a video, and u want to change his format?

Comment: Point 5: Yes, I want to record video from front camera of iPhone and then load it and change its format to mp4

Comment: Have u tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474517/mov-to-mp4-video-conversion-iphone-programmatically

Comment: @gran33 i don't think any of this features at all related to MPMoviePlayerController

Comment: @prasad your link uses MPMoviePlayerContoller

Comment: @gran33 MPMoviePlayerController is only used for playing videos in this tutorials.