# iOS Firebase can't upload mp4 file

Tags: ios, firebase, upload, mp4, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload mp4 file to Firebase, but I'm getting this response:

> Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." UserInfo={object=video/viedo.mp4, bucket=********.appspot.com, ResponseBody=Can not finalize upload.  Current size is 1385472.  Expected final size is 1596602.

I don't have any problems with uploading mov files. Can this be connected with fact that before I upload my mp4 file, I create it from mov file programmatically as in [MOV to Mp4 video conversion iPhone Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474517/mov-to-mp4-video-conversion-iphone-programmatically) using AVURLAsset (conversion is ok as I watch file using AVPlayer) ?

Edit: code for function that create mp4 file from mov file

```
private func encodeVideo(videoURL: URL, completion: @escaping (_ url: URL?) -> ()) {
    let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL, options: nil)

    //Create Export session
    exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: avAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
    if exportSession == nil {
        return
    }

    let documentsDirectory2 = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let filePath = documentsDirectory2.appendingPathComponent("rendered-Video.mp4")

    deleteFile(filePath: filePath)

    exportSession!.outputURL = filePath
    exportSession!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    exportSession!.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    let start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, 0)
    let range = CMTimeRangeMake(start, avAsset.duration)
    exportSession!.timeRange = range

    exportSession!.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {() -> Void in
        switch self.exportSession!.status {
        case .failed:
            completion(nil)
            print("%@",self.exportSession!.error ?? "error saving mp4")
        case .cancelled:
            completion(nil)
            print("Export canceled")
        case .completed:
            completion(filePath)
        default:
            completion(nil)
            break
        }
    })

}
```

I also sometimes get respone

> ResponseBody=Can not finalize upload.  Current size is 1854819.  Expected final size is 1626331.

Comment: From the error message it looks like your app is sending fewer bytes than it initially says. It'll be hard to say more without seeing the specific file and code that generates the problem.

Comment: func to create mp4 file from mov file:

Comment: You ever figure out the issue? I am currently encountering a similar issue.